# Read contact's group in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I've figured out how to fetch a list of the user's contacts using Windows Phone 8. However, given each contact, how do I determine this contact's group? It doesn't seem as if there are any members on the individual Contact object that are of any interest in this case.

Answer (score 1):

After loads of research I have concluded that this can't be done. I'm out of luck. I couldn't even do it using Microsoft's Live SDK for Windows Phone 8.